# Querying a specific cell with known column and row

Tags: ruby, postgresql

I am working with Ruby (not Rails) and PostgeSQL and have been banging my head for hours trying to figure out how to assign the value of a field when you know the column and the row you are trying to cross reference.

I have tried the following:

A database containing cities and linked distances similar to:

```
Cities city1 city2 city3 city4
city1    0    17   13     6
city2    17   0    7      15 
city3          . . . 
city4          . . .
```

and I have tried playing around with the following code:

```
array.each { |city|   #array being the array containing the sorted cities
   from_city = city

   query { |row|
      #row is a hash containing each city as key and distance as val
      #first row: {"Cities"=>"city1", "city1"=>"0", "city2"=>"17",...
      #I have tried doing a row.each and grabbing the value of the specified city key, 
                             but that doesn't work..

   }
}
```

Is there a better way to go about doing this? Basically all I need to know is how I can pull the distance value when I know what two cities I want to use and will assign it to the variable `distance`.

Comment: What are you using to connect to the database? I highly recommend looking into the [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/) gem. It's very powerful and flexible. And, to help your terminology, databases have rows and *fields*, not cells.

Comment: I'm using the pg gem. It's worked great for me so far but I'm just stuck on this. Still new to ruby and databases.. :/

Comment: Assuming you know `to_city`, the solution is as simple as `row[to_city]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd change your database schema (SQL databases aren't really designed to work by column access, and adding a new column everytime you add a city is really painful to do):

```
origin | destination | distance
city1  | city2       | 17
... More rows ...
```

That way looking up the distance between 2 cities is just:

```
conn.exec_params('SELECT distance from cities where origin = $1 and destination = $2', [city1, city2])
```

which will return 1 row with 1 column which is the distance between the two.

Alternatively if your data set is small and doesn't change much there's nothing wrong with storing the data as a file and loading it into memory once at startup. Depends on your use case.

Also, if you're going to do lots of geometry computations, [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/) might be what you want.